# Select2 save current list and values ..

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, ui-select2, jquery-select2-3

I am using Select2.js widget for my site drop-down selection of long list from [here](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)

I have use ajax loading option ..but when i open/click  the drop-down it looses old search text + loaded list and star from new .. i don't want that.. I wanted to keep old search text if there any also if list is loaded previously wanted to keep that as it is and get new at end of scroll ...

code is same as in select2 example  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amitwork/pbrr5dfg/) for test

```
 var $ajax = $(".js-example-data-ajax");
$ajax.select2({
 ajax: {
  url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories",
  dataType: 'json',
  delay: 250,
  data: function (params) {
    return {
        q: params.term?params.term:"a", // search term
      page: params.page
    };
  },
  processResults: function (data, params) {
    params.page = params.page || 1;

    return {
      results: data.items,
      pagination: {
        more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
      }
    };
  },
  cache: true
 },
 escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
 minimumInputLength: 0,
 templateResult: formatRepo,
 templateSelection: formatRepoSelection
});
```

any help to stop this to stop start search on open and keep old test and list saved so user can keep looking for next search after one selection